# PHP mysqli: bind_param in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is a fragment of my code:

```
    $ftype = "HF Custom";
    $stype = "Custom";
    $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE); 
    for($j = 1; $j < $columns; $j++){
        $fname = $pdata[0][$j];
        $startID++; 
        echo "id: ".$startID. "\n";
        if($isExist[$j] <> 1){
        // insert new admin record  
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `admin_custom` (`Fund_ID`, `user_id`, `Fund_Name`,`Fund_Type`,`Fund_Strategy_Classif_1`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('iisss',$startID ,$user_id, $fname, $ftype, $stype);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        }       
.......
    }
    $mysqli->commit();
```

The problem is that when I check records in the admin-custom table, **all Fund_ID fields are the same** and equal to the $startID before entering the loop. All other fields are correct and change according to the $pdata array.

Echoing the $startID shows correct incremented values, it binds with the only one value assigned before entering the loop.

What is wrong here?

THE UPDATE!!!. I've changed the Fund_ID field to varchar(64) and the type of bind_param to 'string'. Now it writes correct strings. So, it looks as int(11) is not enough to represent my Ids --- need to change it to bigint.

Comment: What is the value of `$startID` before entering the loop. Can you provide the table schema?

Comment: The initial value of $startID is 2147483647. The column in the table is declared as int(11)

Comment: so you mean the id column is PK but not AI right?

Comment: There are no keys in that table. See the update in the question description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your update in the comment, if your field `Fund_ID` is an int(11) then the max value is [2147483647](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) which is the initial value for your `$startId`.

Changing to BIGINT would be a better choice.